# mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Tags: php, android, json

I am building an api to encode data in android. In android studio following statement appeared.

> **Warning**:  mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in **C:\xampp\htdocs\androidapi\Search_By_Name.php** on line **6**
>                                                                 {"success":true,"Institute_Name":"Punjab Public High School","Institute_Code":54000}

It is Fetching the data but not showing in Android app
Following is the code of Webapi PHP

```
<?php
include 'dbconnect.php';
if(isset($_POST['Institute_Name'])){
    $name = $_POST['Institute_Name'];
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM institute WHERE Institute_Name = ? " );
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"s", $name);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    //mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement,$Institute_Code, $Institute_Name,$Institute_Type,$Contact_Info ,$Religion ,$Existance ,$Facility ,$Admission_Info ,$Branches ,$About_Institute ,$Scolarship_Programs,$Facility_Info ,$Institute_For ,$Institute_Sector ,$Address ,$radio ,$Degree_Description,$City_ID, $is_approved, $User_ID);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;
        while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $response["success"] = true;
        $response["Institute_Name"] = $Institute_Name;
        $response["Institute_Code"] = $Institute_Code;
        $response["Institute_Type"] = $Institute_Type;
        $response["Contact_Info"] = $Contact_Info;

         echo json_encode($response);


        }  }
 else {
        echo "Name not set";
    }       ?>
```

Comment: Is `$name = $_POST['Institute_Name'];` set as you would expect it to be?

Comment: Yes I only enter the institute name in Android APP