# Write "Like" wildcard with ? keyword in Prepare Statement in MySQL, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Currently I'm trying to Use Like in MySQL Prepare Statement but the issue is i'm not getting a way to write it in prepare statement. I've googled it but didn't get it write. Here is my code.

```
 $name = "Siqarah";
 $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT Institute_Name FROM institute WHERE Institute_Name LIKE ? " );
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"s", $name);
```

ok I got the answer from this link  
[Correct way to use LIKE '%{$var}%' with prepared statements? [mysqli]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385145/correct-way-to-use-like-var-with-prepared-statements-mysqli)

Comment: what errors are you getting and did you successfully connect with mysqli_ and did you execute that query along with fetching the results?

Comment: Is this similar? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8247970

Comment: this also seems to be related to your other question recently http://stackoverflow.com/q/41449169/1415724

Comment: this query doesn't work because I want to use Like with ? and than bind the statement but it is not working

Comment: no it is not @Fred-ii- I want to use Like keyword in my sql prepare statement but I don't get it write

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanKhan ah, ok.

Comment: any Suggestions about how to use like keyword? @Fred-ii-

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanKhan consult the duplicate your question was closed with.